# how to merge two r chunks together using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, merge, chunks, graphing

I have two r chunks that makes two graphs but I want to keep them in two graphs but put them into one r chunk how would I do that

```
accidents %>%
  filter(day_of_week != c("Sunday", "Saturday")) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = time, fill=severity)) +
  geom_density(adjust = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(
    x = "time",
    y = "Density",
    title = "accidents in weekdays"
  )
```

```
accidents %>%
  filter(day_of_week == c("Sunday", "Saturday")) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = time, fill=severity)) +
  geom_density(adjust = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(
    x = "time",
    y = "Density",
    title = "accidents in weekends"
  )
```

Comment: I think the `filter` condition is not correct

Comment: If you keep code for both the plots in the same chunk in markdown it will give print both the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Output your plots to a object like this

ggplot2 ()+ etc
labs() -> p1

ggplot2 ()+ etc
labs() -> p2

print(p1)

print(p2)